# store XML in Array

Tags: php, javascript, xml, arrays

here is link to i want to convert xml to array
http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=22.298569900000000000&lng=70.794301799999970000&radius=7000

 click on above link its return one XML file
i want to store it on array
please help...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small note.. to convert into array is easy as casting (array)

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=22.298569900000000000&lng=70.794301799999970000&radius=7000', true);
$xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `simplexml_load_string` of `php`

For **example**:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```

**Output**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [title] => Forty What?
  [from] => Joe
  [to] => Jane
  [body] =>
   I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
)
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php for more info.

Also you can use https://github.com/gaarf/XML-string-to-PHP-array/blob/master/xmlstr_to_array.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to fetch it and than convert in to simple xml object.

`$responce = file_get_contents('http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=22.298569900000000000&lng=70.794301799999970000&radius=7000', true);
print_r(simplexml_load_string($responce));`